# Special character encoding issue with ServerXMLHTTP

Tags: character-encoding, serverxmlhttp

I am using the following piece of code to retrieve data from a site:

```
    Dim htttpObj As Object
    Set htttpObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")


    htttpObj.SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 300000  

    htttpObj.Open "POST", url, False

    htttpObj.setRequestHeader headerName, headerValue

    htttpObj.Send ("func1=" & func1 & "&func2=" & func2 & "&username=" & login & "&psd=" & password)

    answer = htttpObj.responseText
```

The code works great when retrieving strings like "Cat", "dog", "Hello World!" But it doesn't work when retrieving strings like "Ações".
For instance "Ações" becomes "AÃ§Ãµes" or other special characters.

Does any one know a solution for this issue?

P.s.:I don't get this result when using WinHttp method. But I still have to keep ServerXMLHTTP method as back up for the WinHttp.

Comment: you have a charset mismatch. you have to main the SAME charset throughout the entire rendering pipeline, or connect the "borders" with appropriate translation logic. In your case, probably your output environment is the problem. e.g. a utf-8 response from the server that you're dumping into an iso-8859 environment.

Comment: True, my output environment is UTF-8. I had no idea I was dumping into an iso-8859. Actually I don't know much about this matter, is there any site or link I could use to learn about it and how to translate it?

Comment: I'm just guessing on the 8859, but regardless of what charset it really is, getting unexpected `Ã` chars in your output is a sign of utf text being output in a NON-utf environment.